# Paypal IPN is queued

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm makng tests with paypal in sandbox, everything seemed to be alright and now all my IPN's are in queued.

```
26/02/2018 22:23 GMT+01:00  14Y596669G197780Y   Queued  17H38329HG160924P
26/02/2018 22:12 GMT+01:00  8ME49851HS943061L   Queued  1EH03672T1894124F
26/02/2018 22:00 GMT+01:00  8UC06478BL6408707   Queued  5D964317GL905151A
26/02/2018 21:42 GMT+01:00 (Resent) 8LG46721NE8363107   Sent    1XY34831S8724874H
26/02/2018 21:42 GMT+01:00 (Resent) 9L4497298V591164J   Sent    94P37458725262338
26/02/2018 21:42 GMT+01:00 (Resent) 569519672L0240026   Sent    2U598849HR4915055
26/02/2018 19:37 GMT+01:00  9XX04881AL769230A   Queued  5XX58860PH412420J
26/02/2018 19:15 GMT+01:00 (Resent) 7P451069DG638725K   Sent    2U598849HR4915055
26/02/2018 18:53 GMT+01:00  5GP94745HW022012E   Queued  5BR263785M222113W
26/02/2018 18:53 GMT+01:00  1EM48966K2404790K   Queued  6JE62934XA2366342
26/02/2018 18:39 GMT+01:00  4MY2543097252393P   Queued  49F465780S701944M
26/02/2018 18:29 GMT+01:00  9FW40495JN0415131   Queued  2WF172208D662153G
```

Don't understand the reason, anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I get this often too. It resolves after some time without intervention, as in the IPN status changes to "Sent" and you receive the IPNs. Usually takes 2-3 hours.

Used the PayPal sandbox for so many projects and this never used to happen. I assume they recently throttled the number of IPNs they send in sandbox environment. Hope they remove it or bump it up, as it's rather annoying having to wait or fabricate the IPN.

Edit:

If you are experiencing this issue, a workaround to fabricate your IPN is, in IPN history, click the link in "Message ID" column, then run:

```
curl -d "[IPN message]" [notify URL]
```

Replace value for IPN message and notify URL, both found on the page message ID leads to.

*Note that you will later receive the IPN again when the IPN is out of queue.*

Comment: Thanks for answering Julijan, actually it's more or less how you explained but more complicated. It is supposed that Paypal was making a kind of upgrade that was affecting some of the lasts accounts created. I set a ticket were they explained me the trouble and apologice for the inconviniences. You CANNOT imagine how frustrated I was, first time dealing with this IPN of Paypal and not working and not finding ANY explanation, because of course, it's a simple thing. So, whoever has this problem, go directly to Paypal create a ticket an wait for the answer. It wasn't a code prob.